# Arch ─ 'grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory'

Tags: arch-linux, grub, uefi

### My Current Situation

I'm trying to install Arch Linux following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/PQgyW10xD8s?t=1476 (URL at current time). As he did, I created the `/boot/EFI` directory  and mounted the boot partition on it.

```bsh
$ mkdir /boot/EFI
$ mount /dev/sda1 /boot/EFI
```

And whe I run the following command to install grub it gives me the following log:

```bsh
$ grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --efi-directory=/boot/EFI --recheck --debug
```

```
grub-install: info: executing modprobe -q efivars.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: info: executing efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -w -L grub_uefi -l \EFI\grub_uefi\grubx64.efi.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory
```

### What I Already Tried

- Exit the `arch-chroot` and enable the `efivarfs`.

```
$ exit
$ modprobe efivarfs
$ arch-chroot
```

- Install grub as legacy.

```
$ grub-install --target=i386-pc --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --efi-directory=/boot/EFI --recheck
```

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/1386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the above error when trying to install Arch Linux. In my case I had to boot with the UEFI option from the boot menu, which I entered by pressing F11 (F7 for some UEFIs) during boot.